# How to get a max value from a data frame by date for multiple daily values (sum)?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to utilize a daily sum value to use as a reference for plotting (as a maximum value for the y-axis in a stacked area plot). If there were one value per date, then I would simply use `max(data$value)`, but since there are multiple values per date, I would like to know how to get the maximum daily total value. Below I have provided a simple version of the data I am using:

```
df = data.frame(Date = c(rep(as.Date("2021-01-01"), 4), rep(as.Date("2021-01-02"), 4)),
                Group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
                Value = c(1:4, 2:5))
df
max(df$value)
```

```
> df
        Date Group Value
1 2021-01-01     A     1
2 2021-01-01     B     2
3 2021-01-01     C     3
4 2021-01-01     D     4
5 2021-01-02     A     2
6 2021-01-02     B     3
7 2021-01-02     C     4
8 2021-01-02     D     5
> max(df$Value)
[1] 5
```

Ideally I would like an output like this:

```
> max_by(data = df, Value, by = Date)
[1] 14
```

I know this is not a real command, and I have tried to use dplyr and aggregate without success.

Comment: So you want the largest sum total for a given date? Using `dplyr`, how about `df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarize(daily=sum(Value)) %>% slice_max(daily, n=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  reframe(Value = sum(Value), .by = Date) %>% 
   reframe(Value = max(Value))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
 max(aggregate(Value ~ Date, df, sum)$Value)
[1] 14
```

Comment: +1, why not just use `summarize` here which is more restrictive and requires one value per group? I get the operations you use in `reframe` will result in one value per group, but any benefit to using `reframe` instead of `summarize` in this instance?

Comment: @akrun good question, I added some `microbenchmark` results to test.

Answer (score 0):

I was just curious about performance using the slight variations of `dplyr` suggest by in the comments and other answers:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(Date = c(rep(as.Date("2021-01-01"), 4), rep(as.Date("2021-01-02"), 4)),
                Group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
                Value = c(1:4, 2:5))

set.seed(1)
rows <- sample(1:nrow(df), 1E5, replace = T)

df <- df[rows,]

library(microbenchmark)

(bench <- microbenchmark(
  df %>% 
    reframe(Value = sum(Value), .by = Date) %>% 
    reframe(Value = max(Value)),
  df %>% 
    summarize(Value = sum(Value), .by = Date) %>% 
    summarize(Value = max(Value)),
  df %>% group_by(Date) %>% 
    summarize(daily=sum(Value)) %>% 
    slice_max(daily, n=1),
  df %>% 
    summarize(daily=sum(Value), .by = Date) %>% 
    slice_max(daily, n=1)
)
)
ggplot2::autoplot(bench)
```

**Output**

On my computer `summarize` is *slightly* faster than `reframe` but not significantly so. Interestingly, the use of `group_by` instead of the currently experimental argument `.by` is slower:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                     expr
           df %>% reframe(Value = sum(Value), .by = Date) %>% reframe(Value = max(Value))
       df %>% summarize(Value = sum(Value), .by = Date) %>% summarize(Value = max(Value))
 df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarize(daily = sum(Value)) %>% slice_max(daily,      n = 1)
        df %>% summarize(daily = sum(Value), .by = Date) %>% slice_max(daily,      n = 1)
      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
 5.239101 5.452101 6.415455 5.649851 6.009101 15.4273   100 ab 
 5.180101 5.392100 5.984885 5.589701 5.874251 13.3959   100 a  
 7.551001 7.951001 8.613906 8.161901 8.510801 16.9265   100   c
 5.302501 5.564851 6.802251 5.896051 6.439151 16.6487   100  b
```

[image]